# getting unfortunately stopped error when i define onItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android

I really can't understand what is the problem.

This running very well.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.select);

Resources r = getResources();
values = r.getStringArray(R.array.values);

sSelect = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect);
tvSelect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelect);
```

But this isn't working.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.select);

Resources r = getResources();
values = r.getStringArray(R.array.values);

sSelect = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect);
tvSelect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelect);

sSelect.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

I really want to know what is the problem. Also how can i know what is the problem? There is no error reporting in android programming?

EDIT: **setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner** Which listener can i use with spinner? I don't want to use onItemSelectedListener because It run when app start.

Comment: Have checked the logcat output tab?

Comment: `There is no error reporting in android programming?` - there's, it's called `LogCat`. If you are using Eclipse then you would add this from Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat. Once it is added, inspect carefully the error logs, there you should find the cause of the crash, and the line number in your code that made it.

Comment: @ssantos LogCat says setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner. Which listener can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but chances are you have a typo in `sSelect` resource name, and a `NullPointerException` when calling `setOnItemClickListener`.

Double check there's a `Spinner` named `sSelect` in your `select` layout.

**EDIT**

The right listener for `Spinner` is.-

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

---

```
sSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
});
```

Comment: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner

Comment: But OnItemSelectedListener starts when app starts. Then I don't want to use that. I want to create a dialog when an item selected by user. But when i use OnItemSelectedListener, it shows dialog when app starts!

Comment: Mmh not sure I understand. The listener methods will be called whenever you select an item.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's getting called when default item is selected. Maybe you can have a boolean to prevent the dialog to be shown for the first item selection.

Comment: does everyone use spinner as you say? can't we define a prompt for spinner?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, `setOnItemSelectedListener` is the way to go when handling `Spinner` interaction, never did in any other way, don't know if is there a one better for your scenario, though.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `onItemSelectedListener` for the Spinner. Then, use the `item[0]` value as *"not selected"* or something like that. When you want to call the dialog, write something like:

```
     if(item[position] > 0)
      {
       //start dialog
      }
```

Comment: Then I need to add one more item to my spinner array?

Comment: otherwise the spinner will holds the starting value and automatically starts.and its mandatory to use onitemselectedlistener..this is a good way to handle.

Comment: I use spinner like this. android:spinnerMode="dialog". And default is showing when dialog created. Do you have any idea?